# Oracle search in multiple columns grouped by another column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have table in this structure:

```
id | item | type | string_value | number_value | date_value 
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  | 11   | S    | abcd         | null         | null
2  | 11   | N    | null         | 134.56       | null
3  | 11   | D    | null         | null         | 2017/01/01
4  | 12   | N    | null         | 134.56       | null
5  | 13   | S    | efgh         | null         | null
6  | 13   | N    | null         | 99           | null
7  | 13   | D    | null         | null         | 2000/05/21
8  | 14   | N    | null         | 5            | null
9  | 14   | D    | null         | null         | 2017/01/01
10 | 15   | S    | cd           | null         | null
11 | 15   | N    | null         | 134.56       | null
12 | 15   | D    | null         | null         | 1998/11/01
13 | 11   | S    | aaacddff     | null         | null
14 | 11   | S    | xxxx         | null         | null
```

I want to search `item` by different combinations of value columns(`number_value` or `string_value/number_value` or `string_value/date_value`)

For example: select distinct `item` where `string_value` like '%cd%' **and** `number_value` = 134.56. Expected result is 11 and 15 (12 apply to `number_value` but dont have `string_value`)

There are more value columns I omit for simplicity. Table contains ±100 million rows with joined `item` table (±2 million rows). Primary key is `id` and for one `item` there can be multiple values for same `type`. If `item` has multiple values for same `type` it doesn't matter if every row fits condition but at least one must(like `item` 11 has `string_value` in [abcd, aaacddff, xxxx] - first two fits above like condition). This also involves paging.

Query speed is crucial here. **Oracle10g** DB.

Comment: Have you tried a query yet so that you will at least have a starting reference point?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thats the problem. Simple query: `select distinct item from table where string_value like '%cd%' and number_value = 134.56` return empty result since every row has only one column with value. I also tried OR operator instead AND and merge results in code(java) but I want to avoid this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the merging and checking in the query itself:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 ID, 11 item, 'S' TYPE, 'abcd' string_value, NULL number_value, NULL date_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, 11 item, 'N' TYPE, NULL string_value, 134.56 number_value, NULL date_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 ID, 11 item, 'D' TYPE, NULL string_value, NULL number_value, to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 ID, 12 item, 'N' TYPE, NULL string_value, 134.56 number_value, NULL date_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 ID, 13 item, 'S' TYPE, 'efgh' string_value, NULL number_value, NULL date_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 6 ID, 13 item, 'N' TYPE, NULL string_value, 99 number_value, NULL date_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 7 ID, 13 item, 'D' TYPE, NULL string_value, NULL number_value, to_date('21/05/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 8 ID, 14 item, 'N' TYPE, NULL string_value, 5 number_value, NULL date_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 9 ID, 14 item, 'D' TYPE, NULL string_value, NULL number_value, to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 10 ID, 15 item, 'S' TYPE, 'cd' string_value, NULL number_value, NULL date_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 11 ID, 15 item, 'N' TYPE, NULL string_value, 134.56 number_value, NULL date_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 12 ID, 15 item, 'D' TYPE, NULL string_value, NULL number_value, to_date('01/11/1998', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 13 ID, 11 item, 'S' TYPE, 'aaacddff' string_value, NULL number_value, NULL date_value FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 14 ID, 11 item, 'S' TYPE, 'xxxx' string_value, NULL number_value, NULL date_value FROM dual)
SELECT item
FROM   your_table
WHERE  string_value like '%cd%'
OR     number_value = 134.56
GROUP BY item
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN string_value like '%cd%' THEN string_value END) IS NOT NULL
       AND MAX(CASE WHEN number_value = 134.56 THEN number_value END) IS NOT NULL;

      ITEM
----------
        11
        15
```

Whether this is going to be performant or not is another matter; if you're* going to go with this kind of design, speed is obviously not high on the list of considerations.

*not you specifically; whoever came up with this design in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. For performance aspect I assume that split every `type` to different table and then just use joins would allow me to use AND conditions without grouping?

Comment: Different tables, maybe (but that still doesn't strike me as a brilliant design). Why are multiple rows allowed for the same type? If there were only one value per type, you could just merge them all into a single row and your job would be done for you.

Comment: Each item can have multiple values for same type with different valid time range. First month it can have string_value 'abcd' second month 'xxx' or even null. I omit valid_from and valid_to columns.

Comment: In that case, I'd probably go with a line populated with all three values and whenever a value changes, add a new line with a new valid from (and update the valid_to of the old row)